# marshmallow-mongoengine:Output dump value missing 'None' field

Tags: mongoengine

My project uses flask+mongoengine+marshmallow,When I used marshmallow to serialize the model, the returned value lacked field, and the missing field value was None.When using Django to serialize fields, the None value is still output
model

```py
class Author(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField()
    gender = db.IntField()
    books = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField('Book'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Author(name={self.name!r})>'.format(self=self)


class Book(db.Document):
    title = db.StringField()
```

serializers

```py
class AuthorSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Author


class BookSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Book

author_schema = AuthorSchema()
```

When I do this:

```py
author = Author(name="test1")
>>> author.save()
<Author(name='test1')>
>>> author_schema.dump(author)
MarshalResult(data={'id': '5c80a029fe985e42fb4e6299', 'name': 'test1'}, errors={})
>>>
```

not return the `books` field
I hope to return

```
{
    "name":"test1",
    "books": None
}
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at the source code of the `marshmallow-mongoengine` library, I found the solution `model_skip_values=()` in the tests file.

```py
def test_disable_skip_none_field(self):
        class Doc(me.Document):
            field_empty = me.StringField()
            list_empty = me.ListField(me.StringField())
        class DocSchema(ModelSchema):
            class Meta:
                model = Doc
                model_skip_values = ()
        doc = Doc()
        data, errors = DocSchema().dump(doc)
        assert not errors
        assert data == {'field_empty': None, 'list_empty': []}
```